Is it possible to copy the configuration of the Fruity Parametric EQ 2 from one project to another in FL Studio?
I have an FL Studio project with an instance of the Fruity Parametric EQ 2 plugin with a certain configuration for one channel, and I want to copy that to another project. I tried to copy it manually, but I can't get the settings exactly the same, so I thought that maybe somehow I could save the configuration and upload it to another project. Is this possible?
Is it possible to copy the configuration of the Fruity Parametric EQ 2 from one project to another?

Yes.  There are two ways.  This works for any plugin, although some third party plugins may not behave properly when saving presets, and fruity wrapper settings are not copied (for plugins that use it):


(The slow way):

Save the configuration you wish to copy as a preset, accessed from the drop down menu:

Load your other project, and then load the preset in your other project (don't ask why I have these presets saved):

Optionally, delete the saved preset after.


(The fast way):

Open 2 instances of FL studio, one with each project open.
Click and hold on "Save preset as..." on the preset you wish to copy, as shown above, drag to your other project, and drop on the destination channel strip.

There is also a bonus "very slow way" not mentioned here- every plugin parameter value can be copied.  So in theory, you could copy and paste all 29 available settings from one instance of PEQ2 to another!  Not super practical.  But you could use this to copy a single band, if you like.

The drag & drop one is great
